# Which technique of integration should use to solve the question?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Quote from the paper I read:

Given $F=(1-\lambda)f$ + $\lambda zf'$,

we find that 
$f(z)= \tfrac{1}{\lambda} z^{1- \tfrac{1}{\lambda}}\int_0^zF(t)t^{\tfrac{1}{\lambda}-2}dt.$

My questions is Which technique of integration should use to get answer for $f(z)$?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$

$$
F(z) = (1-\lambda)f + \lambda z f'
$$

re-write as
$$
f' + \frac{(1-\lambda)}{\lambda z}f = \frac{1}{\lambda z}F(z)\tag{*}
$$

using integration factor leads to your solution.

$\textbf{update}$

Eq.(*)  becomes
$$
\mathrm{I.F} = \mathrm{e}^{\int \frac{(1-\lambda)}{\lambda z}dz} = \mathrm{e}^{\frac{(1-\lambda)}{\lambda}\ln z} = \mathrm{e}^{\ln z^{\frac{1-\lambda}{\lambda}}} = z^{\frac{1-\lambda}{\lambda}}
$$

thus
$$
f(z)z^{\frac{1-\lambda}{\lambda}} = \int^{z}_{0} F(t)\frac{1}{\lambda t}t^{\frac{1-\lambda}{\lambda}}dt
$$
here I use a dummy variable t for the integration.

Comment: Which integration factor should used? Can show some steps?...Thanks

Comment: Sorry, i thought you said you only wanted the method? I will update  then

Comment: ok, really thanks a lot...

Comment: For the final equation (right hand side), $lambda$ should be in denominator, correct?

Comment: Oops yep sorry. Typo.

Comment: is ok, nevermind...Once again, thanks for the help...

Comment: Another one I find from the book...
F(z)=(1−λ+μ)f(z) + (λ−μ)zf′(z) + λμz^2f′′(z)
where λ≠0 and μ≠0. Also, z is a complex number.

I suspect it is Cauchy-Euler equation. How to find f? Can show some steps? When μ =0, it will reduce to F given in the question I asked yesterday.

Thanks for help.

Comment: @measure2012 put it in the form of another question and link this answer for some context. For sure let me know the question link, but I'm sure others will get there first ;)

Comment: this is the link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894639/how-to-find-it?noredirect=1#comment1847387_894639