# Second order, inhomogeneous, linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I come across this equation in book

$$F(z)=(1-\lambda + \mu )f(z) + (\lambda - \mu) zf'(z) + \lambda\mu z^2f''(z)$$

where $\lambda \not= 0$ and  $\mu \not= 0.$ 
My question is how to find $f$? Can show some steps?

Thanks for help.

The link which can refer: 
[Which technique of integration should use to solve the question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893907/which-technique-of-integration-should-use-to-solve-the-question/893919?noredirect=1#comment1846899_893919)

Comment: What are $\lambda$, $\mu$? Constants? What about $z$? This looks very much like a Cauchy-Euler equation, if $f$ depends on $z$.

Comment: λ and μ are parameter.

Comment: $z$ a number? Wouldn't rather it be the complex independent variable? As @IanMateus points out, this is a non-homogenous Euler differential equation. For the homogenous part try solutions $f(z) = A z^s$ and solve the polynomial for $s$. For the particular solution, you may want to follow this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652362/find-the-form-of-a-second-linear-independent-solution-when-the-two-roots-of-indi/652468#652468. Cheers!